# Overuse of i.e. and e.g

Tags: writing, writing-style

I got used to using 'i.e.' and 'e.g.' to give more details or give examples, but I have been told that I overuse them. When is it appropriate to remove them? When should I absolutely use them?

I feel I should use it all the time if I use one of those at least once in a manuscript.

Comment: Shouldn’t the title be “Overuse of, e.g., i.e.?”

Comment: It's not really an academics question, more of a grammar or English usage question.

Comment: @puppetsock but as far as I know it is used in academic writing, thus my question in 'Academia' :)

Comment: @JonCuster Maybe? Not a native here

Comment: @PierreO So are cars, used in academia. But we don't usually answer auto mechanics questions.

Comment: @puppetsock in that case, cars would be the subject of a study (or there are academic cars I am not aware of) and not a technique used by academics.
In the time, you took writing this comment, I could have gotten an answer. ;)

Comment: @PierreO - that comment was mostly tongue-in-cheek, but it does demonstrate how those both break up the flow of sentences.

Comment: @JonCuster That was definitely a good one ;)

Comment: What do you mean by, "I feel I should use it all the time"? Like: any place you'd say "for example", use "e.g." instead? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Closer voters: I think this is a valuable question to have here on Academia.SE. If you are concerned about it, perhaps edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I meant to stay consistent in my writing, if I use it once, I should use it each time, instead of alternating "for example" and "e.g.", or "i.e." and "that is".

Comment: @PierreO: I suspect that the critic would be equally aggravated by lots of "for examples" running around (regardless of abbreviations).

Answer (score 8):

If you are told by an editor or a reviewer that it is too much, then make a change to satisfy them.

Otherwise don't worry too much about it, though it is a good idea to keep such things as overuse of any sort of technique or phrasing in mind.

The key is that the language should flow. If it gets stilted in any way, make an adjustment. We all probably need to improve.

But note that taking them all out and replacing them with "that is" and "for example" might seem just as stilted.

Comment: I was thinking more of removing them with just parenthesis.
"This was observed in the literature (for fish, Johns 2010, for bears, Keith 2019)" instead of 
"This was observed in the literature (e.g. for fish, Johns 2010, for bears, Keith 2019)"

Comment: @PierreO "This was observed in the literature for several species, including fish (Johns 2010) and bears (Keith 2019)."

Comment: @lighthousekeeper not sure why I am not used to write it like this but this is a very good example!

Comment: @lighthousekeeper or even just "This was observed in fish (Johns 2010) and bears (Keith 2019)."

Answer (score -10):

You are writing in English, not Latin.  You should avoid using e.g or i.e.  That's what my high school English teachers told me.

If replacing them with "for example" and "that is" makes your prose too stilted, then you need to reword your sentences.

Writing is not easy.  Unfortunately, artful writing is not particularly rewarded, so few academics bother.

Comment: The **e.g** and **i.e.** are very popular in research papers (at least in health, economics, and finance areas)

Comment: @NoviceMindset and ecology, biology, medicine, physics, chemistry...etc :) I have seen it in many other fields

Comment: Normally teachers teach pupils how to fill a page. The English teachers, as well those teaching any other language, do not think in terms of number of characters. At least they won't put a numerical upper limit to them.

Comment: Your teacher was incorrect. "i.e." and "e.g." are just as legitimate English as other import words like "pajamas" and "hors d'oeuvres"